# PHP <?= operator

Tags: php, operators

Can anyone explain what this line of code means? I don't know much of php at all, but I need to be able to read this.

`<?= !empty($val['code_id']) ? $val['code_id'] : '-' ?>`

I know that using a `?` and `:` is short hand for if/then, but I don't know what the `<?=    ?>` means.

I couldn't find anything on Google that was helpful.

Comment: `<?=` is short tag syntax for `<?php echo` and the rest of it is a ternary.

Comment: Need to brush up a little on your googling then my dear

Comment: However, Andrea `<?` is short hand for `<?php` and will only work if short tags are enabled. You will get a parse error if it isn't and if you plan on using that.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I couldn't find anything on Google because I didn't even know what to search.

Comment: it will echo $val['code_id'] if it is not null else it will echo '-'

Comment: @Rijin that isn't what the question was about ;-)

Comment: <?= $data ?>  same as <?php echo $data; ?>